# onchildclick case statement android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, switch-statement

the project run ok,the case 3 child clicks ok ,but in case 2 clicks it display activity from case 3 or activity that I deleted it before then on return it display the activity that I wanted
(when I click microbiology it display pedodontics then on return click it display Microbiology)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.freedental.blogspot.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                switch(groupPosition) {
                 case 1:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                    case 0: 
                        Intent c1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv1Activity.class);
                        startActivity(c1);
                        break;

                    }
                 case 2:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                    case 0: 
                        Intent d1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv1Activity.class);
                        startActivity(d1);
                        break;
                    case 1: 
                        Intent d2= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv2Activity.class);
                        startActivity(d2);
                        break;
                    case 2: 
                        Intent d3= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv3Activity.class);
                        startActivity(d3);
                        break;
                    case 3: 
                        Intent d4= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv4Activity.class);
                        startActivity(d4);
                        break;
                    case 4: 
                        Intent d5= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv5Activity.class);
                        startActivity(d5);
                        break;
                    case 5: 
                        Intent d6= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv6Activity.class);
                        startActivity(d6);
                        break;
                    case 6: 
                        Intent d7= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv7Activity.class);
                        startActivity(d7);
                        break;
                    case 7: 
                        Intent d8= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv8Activity.class);
                        startActivity(d8);
                        break;


                    }
                case 3:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                    case 0: 
                        Intent a1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv9Activity.class);
                        startActivity(a1);
                    break;
                    case 1: 
                        Intent a2= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv10Activity.class);
                        startActivity(a2);
                        break;
                    case 2: 
                        Intent a3= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv11Activity.class);
                        startActivity(a3);
                        break;
                    case 3: 
                        Intent a4= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv12Activity.class);
                        startActivity(a4);
                        break;
                    case 4: 
                        Intent a5= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv13Activity.class);
                        startActivity(a5);
                        break;
                    case 5: 
                        Intent a6= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv14Activity.class);
                        startActivity(a6);
                        break;
                    case 6: 
                        Intent a7= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv15Activity.class);
                        startActivity(a7);
                        break;
                    case 7: 
                        Intent a8= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv16Activity.class);
                        startActivity(a8);
                        break;


                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            });
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("1st Grade lectures");
        listDataHeader.add("2nd Grade lectures");
        listDataHeader.add("3rd Grade lectures");
        listDataHeader.add("4th Grade lectures");
        listDataHeader.add("5th Grade lectures");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> first = new ArrayList<String>();
        first.add("Under Construction");

        List<String> second = new ArrayList<String>();
        second.add("Prosthodontics");
        second.add("Other under con");

        List<String> third = new ArrayList<String>();
        third.add("Microbiology");
        third.add("Pathology");
        third.add("Pharmacology");
        third.add("Surgery");
        third.add("Operative");
        third.add("Prosthodontics");
        third.add("Radiology");
        third.add("Cummunity");


        List<String> fourth = new ArrayList<String>();
        fourth.add("periodontology");
        fourth.add("pedodontics");
        fourth.add("Orthodontics");
        fourth.add("Prosthodontics");
        fourth.add("Oral Pathology");
        fourth.add("Oral Surgery");
        fourth.add("General Surgery");
        fourth.add("General Medicine");

        List<String> fifth = new ArrayList<String>();
        fifth.add("Under Construction");


        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), first); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), second);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), third);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), fourth);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), fifth);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `break` statement after `case 1` and `case 2` :

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            switch(groupPosition) {
             case 1:
                switch (childPosition) {
                case 0: 
                    Intent c1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv1Activity.class);
                    startActivity(c1);
                    break;

                }

=======>>>>>    break;

             case 2:
                switch (childPosition) {
                case 0: 
                    Intent d1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv1Activity.class);
                    startActivity(d1);
                    break;
                case 1: 
                    Intent d2= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv2Activity.class);
                    startActivity(d2);
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    Intent d3= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv3Activity.class);
                    startActivity(d3);
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    Intent d4= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv4Activity.class);
                    startActivity(d4);
                    break;
                case 4: 
                    Intent d5= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv5Activity.class);
                    startActivity(d5);
                    break;
                case 5: 
                    Intent d6= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv6Activity.class);
                    startActivity(d6);
                    break;
                case 6: 
                    Intent d7= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv7Activity.class);
                    startActivity(d7);
                    break;
                case 7: 
                    Intent d8= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv8Activity.class);
                    startActivity(d8);
                    break;


                }

==========>>>>> break;               

            case 3:
                switch (childPosition) {
                case 0: 
                    Intent a1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv9Activity.class);
                    startActivity(a1);
                break;
                case 1: 
                    Intent a2= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv10Activity.class);
                    startActivity(a2);
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    Intent a3= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv11Activity.class);
                    startActivity(a3);
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    Intent a4= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv12Activity.class);
                    startActivity(a4);
                    break;
                case 4: 
                    Intent a5= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv13Activity.class);
                    startActivity(a5);
                    break;
                case 5: 
                    Intent a6= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv14Activity.class);
                    startActivity(a6);
                    break;
                case 6: 
                    Intent a7= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv15Activity.class);
                    startActivity(a7);
                    break;
                case 7: 
                    Intent a8= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webv16Activity.class);
                    startActivity(a8);
                    break;


                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        });
```